# PHP/PEAR - Retain trailing zeros when creating spreadsheets

Tags: php, pear

I'm using the PHP PEAR package to generate excel spreadsheets. I have data of type double with trailing zeros that need to be retained. How can I preserve this data without having the Worksheet::writeNumber function truncate the zeros? I've tried changing the format string in the pack function but no luck yet.

Comment: How are you verifying that it is the writeNumber function that is truncating?  Excel for example defaults to 0 precision numbers if there is no value after the decimal point.  Unless changed via the format settings.  If you have not already I would recommend checking the output in a text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `'` before it, e.g.

```
"'" . $number
```